# Knockout nested objects bindings not working (objects undefined)

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

So I have four models:

- Lobby (the view model)
- Messages
- Campaigns
- Campaign

And I have them set up like so:

```
       Lobby: function(Messages, Campaigns) {
            var self = this;
            self.chat = new Messages();
            self.campaigns = new Campaigns();
        },
        Campaigns: function() {
            var self = this;
            self.campaigns = ko.observableArray();
        },
        Messages: function() {
            var self = this;
            self.message = ko.observable("");
            self.messages = ko.observableArray();
        },
        Campaign: function(campaign) {
            var self = this;
            var status = ["In Lobby", "In Game", "Finished"];
            self.Id = ko.observable(campaign.Id);
            self.url = ko.observable("/matchmaking/" + campaign.Id);
            self.mapName = ko.observable(campaign.Map);
            self.mapImage = ko.observable("/Images/"+ campaign.Map +".jpg");
            self.notes = ko.observable(campaign.Notes);
            self.status = ko.observable(status[campaign.status]);
        }
```

And I have a simple binding to view the each message in the chat model:

```
   <div id="chat-messages" data-bind="foreach:chat.messages" style=" max-height: 250px; min-height: 80px; overflow-y: auto;">
                        <div data-bind="text:$data"></div>
                    </div>
```

Apply bindings is added:

```
  ko.applyBindings(this.viewModel); //where this.viewModel is an instance of Lobby
```

However I get the following error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "foreach: function
>   (){return chat.messages }" Message: chat is not defined

I've tried putting them all in one model, splitting them out like this. Al sorts, it just doesn't want to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: `foreach:chat().messages`?

Comment: @artm is probably spot on, kindof a typo I'd guess, happens to the best of us :-) (@QBM5 `chat` is an observable on `Lobby`)

Comment: Yes artm, thank you, post as answer and I will accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Lobby`'s `chat` is a function of `Messages` type so using the binding `data-bind="foreach:chat.messages"` translates to `Lobby.chat` which returns a function. So you need to change your binding to `data-bind="foreach:chat().messages"`

Answer (score 1):

your problem is that `chat` is an observable and as such you should call `chat().messages` :)